# Java - Sorting List by child list size

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I'm trying to order the list below of workers by the quantity of this days . But I can't get the right way to do that. I can order them by ID for example on this way:

```
workers.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Worker::getId)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I can't find the way to use the ***Worker.getDays().size()*** to order them....

```
    "workers": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "days": ["Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "days": ["Tuesday", "Thursday"]
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "days": ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Friday"]
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "days": ["Thursday"]
        },   
]
```

Hope I could find a nice solution, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a [lambda-expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to get the days of a worker and the size..

```
  List<Worker> workersSortedByDaysSize = workers.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(w -> w.getDays().size()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This assumes days is not `null`.

Comment: It works perfectly, I didn't how to build the lambda, thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. I hope the linked documentation will help you to understand how to write lambda-expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List<Worker> sorted = workers
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(w -> w.getDays().size()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

`workers.stream().sorted((w1, w2) -> w1.getDays().size() - w2.getDays().size()).collect(Collectors.toList());`
 or do w2-w1 to reverse the list